# Implement field wise searching in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I have to add functionality to search for fields from model with different input fields for different columns.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-a-text-filter-to-django-admin-5d1db93772d8) from medium.com and have implemented it like

**models.py**

```
class WallmartRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'wallmart_records'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**admin.py**

```
class InputFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    template = 'admin/input_filter.html'

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        pass

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return ((),)

    def choices(self, changelist):
        # Grab only the "all" option.
        all_choice = next(super().choices(changelist))
        all_choice['query_parts'] = (
            (k, v)
            for k, v in changelist.get_filters_params().items()
            if k != self.parameter_name
        )
        yield all_choice


class WallmartNameFilter(InputFilter):
    parameter_name = 'name'
    title = _('Name')

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() is not None:
            name = self.value()

            return queryset.filter(
                name=name
            )


@admin.register(WallmartRecord)
class WallmartRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [
        'WallmartNameFilter',
        'not_exists_in_amazon',
        'arbitrase_generated'
    ]
```

But this is giving error as

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'arbitrase.admin.WallmartRecordAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'WallmartNameFilter', which does not refer to a Field.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list_filter you have to give your custom filter class name.

```
list_filter = [YourFilterClass]
```

Don't give it as a string.